# How can I change badge total color in Angular bootstrap calendar

Tags: colors, calendar, badge, angular-bootstrap

I didn't found the solution to change the class of badge total on event cell ?
By default, it's badge-important, but I find the red a bit agressive when you have many events in Month view.

how could I change the class ?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding default css, have a class in your css file like

```
.badge-important {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I've thought about this solution but it will override it for every badge-important I use in my page. I'll do this if there is no better solution.

Comment: Is it possible to change badge color if event date is greater than today?